# select all the words in Microsoft Office Word

Tags: ms-word

I'm not asking for "select All" texts in MS Word! neither using "CTRL" to select! or Even "Find". Ok?
My Question is : How Can I select all the words having e.g. "Home"
e.g.

I'm Going Home. I'm Coming Home. I love My Home.

I want to select all these "Home" and change their colors to RED (e.g.).

In My Case, The word I've been working on is repeated 1000 times. I can't select them one by one!

If this is not Possible, Is there a word processor can solve my problem?

I Need Your Help! Thanks A lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

You can use find and replace all for that.  Click the More >  > button, which will then turn into less, and you can click on format which will allow you to adjust the font **and its color** then hit replace all.

[image]

Comment: Don't get stuck on the word format.  Take a look at the additional screenshot I provided.  you can replace home with home in a red color.

Comment: Thank You SOOOOOOOO Much ! <3<3<3<3<3<3<3

Answer (score 1):

You want "Find and Replace": CTRL-H.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-and-replace-text-and-other-data-in-a-Word-document-c6728c16-469e-43cd-afe4-7708c6c779b7

"To search for text with specific formatting, type the text in the Find what box. To find formatting only, leave the box blank.

Click Format, and then select the formats that you want to find and replace. For example, to find highlighted text, click Format > Highlight; to find bold text, click Format > Font, and then in the Find Font dialog box, select Bold in the Font style list.
Click the Replace with box, click Format, and then select the replacement formats.

NOTE: If you also want to replace the text, type the replacement text in the Replace with box.
To find and replace each instance of the specified formatting, click Find Next, and then click Replace. To replace all instances of the specified formatting, click Replace All."

Comment: If you don't provide the Format when searching, the application will find all instances of the text you provide without regard to format.